# Sql search Result between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, ajax

i have a table name expected expense in which i have 4 columns name Expense_title, Amount, expense_category, date and all the 4 columns have var char type. When I try to find expense between two dates it work fine for same year, e.g. 11/27/2018 and 12/27/2018, but it doesn't get any result when I try to find expense between two years, e.g. 12/27/2018 And 01/27/2019. please help

I am trying this query

```
SELECT *
from expected_expense
WHERE Date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using ? Consider casting your dates to an actual `date` type.

Comment: i am using mysql

Comment: _all the 4 columns have var char type_. This is wrong. The datatypes exist for a reason.

Comment: and date type is varchar

Comment: Use proper `date` data type, and the problem is gone!

Comment: @SalmanA but why?

Comment: Because for every DB out there date stored as varchar got a different format then a date format ... so 12/27/2018 as varchar <> 12/27/2018 as date ... also, make sure you got data actually on 12/27/2018, i think all your expenses are actually on 11th month (before 12/27/2018)

Comment: You need to convert your string Date to Date-Format. Then only your comparison will work for dates properly. Try like this: select date_format(str_to_date('12/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y%m');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, this is because of the `varchar` type.

The `between` operator is nothing different than doing two closed inequalities for its range limits. In your example,
`between 12/27/2018 And 01/27/2019`

will be changed internally to

`>= 12/27/2018 and <= 01/27/2019`

but these are not dates, they are text. And the second one is less than the first, so nothing will be returned. It's like asking the question: which letter comes after q but before b? None.

Either change the fields to datetime, or use conversion functions in your query.

Comment: Either change the fields to datetime or don't bother using a relational database

Comment: Why are you commenting such on this answer?

Comment: Because I disagree with the final sentence of your answer, which is otherwise correct

Comment: While I agree using datetime in the schema directly is the preferred thing to do from a black box perspective, one can never know what the case is behind the question. Maybe the op doesnt have schema modification rights. Maybe this is a view from an originally indeed `datetime` field. Maybe the char is there because of some data bridge.